# How do I divide an element from a list by an integer in Python?

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror

I'm getting the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'` error. I understand why, but I don't know how to divide the parameters from the input by the integer.

```
from ast import literal_eval


def get_area(x, y, z):
    area = ((x + y) / 2) * z 
    return area

param = (input('give parameters in the following format: "[[base_1], [base_2], [height]]"'))
param = literal_eval(param)

print(get_area(param[0], param[1], param[2]))
```

Comment: Where is your error occurring?

Comment: under the get_area function where I try to divide (x + y) by 2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're asking the user to enter their input as an array of arrays. You can fix this problem in two ways:

**By changing the function to use the element inside the arrays:**

```
def get_area(x, y, z):
    area = ((x[0] + y[0]) / 2) * z[0]
    return area
```

**Or by accepting just a list from the user:**

```
input('give parameters in the following format: "[base_1, base_2, height]"')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is just how you input the numbers. I tested it entering: 1,2,3 and [1,2,3] and it's OK. If I enter [[1],[2],[3]] as suggested in your input sentence... it fails!

Answer (score 0):

[[base_1], [base_2], [height]]

The bracket surrounding [base_1] makes it a list, and you want a number.

So remove the brackets surrounding base1,base2 and height and it should work.

[base_1, base_2, height]